# При запуске выдает кучу ошибок, как исправить? (Pytest+selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

Код:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Users\nneki\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get("https://www.saucedemo.com/")`
```

Ошибки:

```
"C:\Program Files\Python310\python.exe" C:/Users/nneki/PycharmProjects/test/main.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nneki\PycharmProjects\test\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
  File "C:\Users\nneki\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .firefox.webdriver import WebDriver as Firefox  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\nneki\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 32, in <module>
    from .service import DEFAULT_EXECUTABLE_PATH, Service
  File "C:\Users\nneki\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\service.py", line 20, in <module>
    from selenium.webdriver.common import (service, utils)
  File "C:\Users\nneki\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 3, in <module>
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'ChromeOptions' (most likely due to a circular import)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Попробуйте переложить .exe файл в другой путь, например, в папку с проектом.
2. У вас компилятор не понимает, что такое chromeoptions.
   Попробуйте его импортнуть

   from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

Answer (score 0):

Вот мой стартовый набор импортов для драйвера, но прежде нужно еще импортнуть в терминале эту штуку - pip install webdriver-manager, а в самом тестовом файле код который приведен ниже:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service



options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.set_capability("pageLoadStrategy", "eager")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.maximize_window()
```